# google maps typeerror with jquery

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am getting a type error for my map

```
TypeError: google is undefined
var marker = new google.maps.Marker( 
line:280
```

and

```
TypeError: google is undefined
... new google.maps.LatLng(
line:270
```

seems like i am loosing scope? im initializing outside of jquery but i want to call a function that creates those objects within jquery code.

any suggestions?

http://jareddlc.com/map.php

to trigger the case, type a city in the box and click submit. make sure you have enabled your console as i outputting via console.log

Comment: `google` is a global variable (maps.google.com assigns `window.google`), there shouldn't be any scope issues. What do I have to do on your page to trigger the error?

Comment: There's no such thing as "outside" (or inside) jQuery. It's all javascript. If you're getting that error, then either the `.../maps/api/...` lib is not installed on the page, or some statement in your javascript has overwritten `google`, `google.maps` or `google.maps.Marker`. It is extremely unlikely to be a scope issue for the reason pointed out by @Barmar.

Comment: enter a city and hit submit. to trigger it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple places where you create a "locale" google-variable:

Line 78 and line 289:

```
var windows=0,osx=0,linux=0,hotmail=0,yahoomail=0,gmail=0,bing=0,yahoo=0,google=0
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Line 101:

```
google += 1;
```

Use different names  for these local variables, or explicitly refer to the global google-variable when needed by prepending `window.`, e.g:

```
new window.google.maps.Marker(/*....*/);
```

Comment: thanks! I was working late and i cant believe i missed that :P